# Disable pagination inspector on drf_yasg

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I'm using `drf_yasg` to create my swagger document but I have an issue with `PaginationInspector`. In one of my views I declare a paginator and in swagger, is shown as the default pagination for swagger.

Something like this:

```
count*  integer #This info is generated automatically by swagger
next    string($uri) #This info is generated automatically by swagger
x-nullable: true #This info is generated automatically by swagger
previous:   string($uri) #This info is generated automatically by swagger
            x-nullable: trueç

results: (THE BODY I ACTUALLY WANT TO SHOW)
```

[image]

I would like that the swagger ignore that pagination but haven’t found any info related to it.

I try using the decorator, initially I though it could be something like `@swagger_auto_schema(paginator_inspectors=False)` but it doesn't work and I can't find anything useful on the docs. Thanks in advance

oh and just in case this is my view:

```py
class CharacterView(ListChView):
    class OutputSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        id = serializers.CharField(source="external_id")
        created_at = serializers.DateTimeField()

    pagination_class = CustomPagination
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override  [**get_paginated_response_schema**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/df92e57ad6c8394ca54654dfc7a2722f822ed8c8/rest_framework/pagination.py#L232) method.

```py
class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    ...
    # add
    def get_paginated_response_schema(self, schema):
        return {
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'results': schema,
            },
        }
```